# How to access Infinispan Memcached Server cache container from a Spymemcached Client?

Tags: caching, memcached, client, infinispan

I've created a distributed cluster using Memcached over Infinispan.

Now, I need to access to my cache using SpyMemcached client.

I tried this :

```
AuthDescriptor ad2 = new AuthDescriptor(new String[]{"PLAIN"}, new PlainCallbackHandler("username", "cryptedpass"));
ConnectionFactoryBuilder factoryBuilder = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder();
SerializingTranscoder transcoder=new SerializingTranscoder();  
transcoder.setCompressionThreshold(1024);  

ConnectionFactory cf = factoryBuilder
   .setTranscoder(transcoder)
   .setOpTimeout(10000)
   .setMaxReconnectDelay(10000)
.setTimeoutExceptionThreshold(1998)   
   .setLocatorType(Locator.CONSISTENT)  
   .setFailureMode(FailureMode.Retry)   
   .setUseNagleAlgorithm(false)
   .setProtocol(Protocol.BINARY)                
   .setAuthDescriptor(ad2).build();
MemcachedClient memcachedClient = new MemcachedClient(cf,Collections.singletonList(new InetSocketAddress("ONE_NODE_IP_ADDRESS", 11211)));
memcachedClient.add("test", 0, "testData");
```

But I get this error :

```
2014-03-21 19:19:22.952 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Operation canceled because authentication or reconnection and authentication has taken more than one second to complete.
```

Already, It seems to me a bit confusing. If over a machine I have multiple caches, which cache would my client choose???

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan supports only the text version of Memcached protocol.